# how to encrypt and decrypt URL in angular

Tags: angular, angular6

In my project, two modules here(Staff, Agent ). I click Agent module list and URL shows Agent /list and update one Agent , URL passing id  corresponding id . But i want encrypted data passing update and list in URL. So how to pass encrypted (user not understanding) values in Angular 6

```
return this.repository.postData('api/agent/list', requestObj);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using atob() and btoa() functions can give you what you are looking for. For some of the btoa() functions you might need to do the toString() method if the value is non string ex.(NUMBER)**

*Non Encrypted Routing*

```
//http://localhost:4200/api/id=1
this.router.navigate(['/api',{ id: '1' },]);
```

*Encrypted Routing*

```
//http://localhost:4200/api/id=S2T2A3
this.router.navigate(['/api',{ id: btoa('1') },]);
```

***How to get the id value on next page***

*Non Decrypt ID*

```
this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')!;
```

*Decrypt ID*

```
this.id = atob(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')!);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using `atob` and `btoa` functions. Here is an example:

```
console.log(btoa("some data")); // this will encode the data 
console.log(atob("some data")); // this will decode the data
```

So you need to implement like this:

```
return this.repository.postData('api/agent/list', btoa(requestObj));
```

Comment: Adding btoa() functions in my project. But, update first record url looks likes api/agent/details/1 . Sir, i change id is 1 to 2 data is not retrieved.I think is useful but  i ask update id shown  encrypted string looks like 'api/agent/details/SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh' . Is it possible ???

Comment: @SARAVANAKUMAR Yes if i encode the 'password' string using btoa('password'); it look like this 
console.log(btoa("password")); // o/p cGFzc3dvcmQ=
so in ts when you want to perform the api call or you just want to use the encoded value all you need to do is decoding the encrypted string by using atob(<encrypted-data>);

Answer (score 1):

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute, ) {}
```

> You can access your params in this way on your onInit function:

```
const abc = this.activatedroute.snapshot.params['abc'];
const xy = this.activatedroute.snapshot.params['xy'];
```

**Note: your url should be something like localhost:4200/lib/123/32**

then your sosid will have the value 123 and xy will have the value 32.

The way you want to encrypt and decrypt is up to you. Theare infinite ways to do that. It just depends by you. For example you can decide to shift every ASCII key by one when encoding, and then shitf them back when decoding.

**For example, if you decide that shift and the url is .../lib/353/47, then the real data will be :**

```
abc : 242
xy : 36
```

Comment: My Expected URL looks like 'localhost:4200/api/agent/details/SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh' . Is it possible ??? Please give any suggest...
But, my actual URL 'localhost:4200/api/agent/details/1'

Comment: sir any possibilities is here..please suggest me @Naveen