# show user a fake route in angular

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular-fullstack

I am working on a full stack development using Angular, Node and MySQL. I want to ask if there's a way I can add a fake route to show it to a user. Let me explain, I want to add a route of let's say:

```
http://localhost:4200/#/**table**
```

I want to show it to user as:

```
http://localhost:4200/#/**somefakeroute**
```

Behind the scenes, in my code, this path doesn't exist but, shows to user as one. Is there a way to do that in angular? To show a different route name to a user than what it really is? I want to protect my routes by doing this instead of using route guards.

Comment: I think, changing it to some `fakeroute` is as effective and secure as adding `encryption` at the frontend .

Comment: Actually, I have to implement my project on a server that's not on the web. So, I don't want to add routes guard but rather, some fake route to confuse user. The users aren't technical so, this will work totally fine. The user will not be able to access the page by writing the url like: http://localhost:4200/#/**somefakeroute** because **somefakeroute** doesn't exist. They can only access it by writing the url: http://localhost:4200/#/**table** and they won't know this until they visit the source code and see what the routers are defined as in the code. I want to ask is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can do something better than showing fake routes.

1. You can use encryption. [Encrypting routes in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55862110/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-url-in-angular)
2. [Navigation Extras in angular](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras), you can use this to create alias names for routes,
   example:

```
this.router.navigate(['/view'], { skipLocationChange: true });
```